# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error, noclassdeffounderror, android-proguard

getting error for the line `HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();`

logcat stack-trace below

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
W/System.err:     at com.jd.reg.utils.ExportUtils.exportCustomer(Utils.java:107)
W/System.err:     at com.jd.reg.activity.UpdateActivity.exportCustomer(UpdateActivity.java:111)
W/System.err:     at com.jd.reg.activity.UpdateActivity$4.onClick(UpdateActivity.java:258)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have already added below in `proguard-project.txt`

```
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.*
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.util.*
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.ss.*
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.ss.util.*
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.ss.format.*
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.ddf.*
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.*
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.hpsf.*
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.poifs.*
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.*
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.sl.draw.*
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.sl.draw.geom.*
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.sl.draw.binding.*
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.*
-dontwarn org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
```

and below in `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-keep class org.** { *; }
```

along with above **-dontwarn** lines

Still getting the error even after multiple rebuild and restarts of android studio.

What exactly I'm missing??

Comment: Same here... I am struggling with the same runtime-error.

Answer (score 0):

Add below rule into proguard

```
-keep public class org.apache.poi.** {*;}
```